# Execution of subquery within table class gives class not found [doctrine]

Tags: doctrine, subquery

In table class Ouders I do the following query:

```
$q = $this->createQuery('o')
    ->where('o.ouderid IN (SELECT DISTINCT k.parentid FROM Kinderen k WHERE k.schoolid = ?)', $schoolcode)
    ->orderBy('o.achternaam');
```

As you can see it has a subquery to the table class Kinderen.

Why does it give the error?:

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: Couldn't find class Kinderen
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Table.php(256): Doctrine_Table->initDefinition()
#1 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Connection.php(1126): Doctrine_Table->__construct('Kinderen', Object(Doctrine_Connection_Mysql), true)
#2 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query.php(1934): Doctrine_Connection->getTable('Kinderen')
#3 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query.php(1732): Doctrine_Query->loadRoot('Kinderen', 'k')
#4 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query/From.php(88): Doctrine_Query->load('Kinderen k')
#5 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(2077): Doctrine_Query_From->parse('Kinderen k')
#6 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query.php(1160): Doctrine_Query_Abstract->_processDqlQueryPart('from', Array)
#7 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query.php(1126): Doctrine_Query->buildSqlQuery(true)
#8 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query.php(843): Doctrine_Query->getSqlQuery()
#9 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query.php(813): Doctrine_Query->parseSubquery('(SELECT DISTINC...')
#10 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query.php(697): Doctrine_Query->parseFunctionExpression('(SELECT DISTINC...')
#11 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query/Where.php(121): Doctrine_Query->parseClause('(SELECT DISTINC...')
#12 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query/Where.php(81): Doctrine_Query_Where->_buildSql('o.ouderid', 'IN', '(SELECT DISTINC...')
#13 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query/Condition.php(92): Doctrine_Query_Where->load('o.ouderid IN (S...')
#14 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(2077): Doctrine_Query_Condition->parse('o.ouderid IN (S...')
#15 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query.php(1160): Doctrine_Query_Abstract->_processDqlQueryPart('where', Array)
#16 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query.php(1126): Doctrine_Query->buildSqlQuery(true)
#17 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(958): Doctrine_Query->getSqlQuery(Array)
#18 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php(1026): Doctrine_Query_Abstract->_execute(Array)
#19 /var/www/bredeschool/app/application/models/OudersTable.php(34): Doctrine_Query_Abstract->execute()
#20 /var/www/bredeschool/app/application/controllers/OudersController.php(44): Model_OudersTable->getView('111')
#21 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): OudersController->listAction()
#22 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('listAction')
#23 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#24 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#25 /var/www/bredeschool/app/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#26 /var/www/bredeschool/bredeschoolzuidoost.nl/app/index.php(28): Zend_Application->run()
#27 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'ouders',
  'action' => 'list',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

**Kinderen model**

```
// Connection Component Binding
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->bindComponent('Model_Kinderen', 'doctrine');

/**
 * Model_Base_Kinderen
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 * 
 * @property integer $kindid
 * @property integer $parentid
 * @property string $naamouder
 * @property string $naambov1
 * @property string $telefoonbov1
 * @property string $relatiebov1
 * @property string $naambov2
 * @property string $telefoonbov2
 * @property string $relatiebov2
 * @property string $voornaam
 * @property string $tussenvoegsel
 * @property string $achternaam
 * @property date $geboortedatum
 * @property string $jomei
 * @property integer $schoolid
 * @property string $jufmeester
 * @property integer $groep
 * @property string $bijzonderheden
 * @property string $zelfstandigheid
 * @property string $opvang
 * @property string $dagvdweek
 * @property string $overig
 * @property string $bso
 * @property string $zwemdiploma
 * @property timestamp $aanmaakdatum
 * @property string $aanmeldwijze
 * 
 * @package    ##PACKAGE##
 * @subpackage ##SUBPACKAGE##
 * @author     ##NAME## <##EMAIL##>
 * @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 7490 2010-03-29 19:53:27Z jwage $
 */
abstract class Model_Base_Kinderen extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('kinderen');
        $this->hasColumn('kindid', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('parentid', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('naamouder', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('naambov1', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('telefoonbov1', 'string', 20, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '20',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('relatiebov1', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('naambov2', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('telefoonbov2', 'string', 20, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '20',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('relatiebov2', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('voornaam', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('tussenvoegsel', 'string', 50, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '50',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('achternaam', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('geboortedatum', 'date', 25, array(
             'type' => 'date',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '25',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('jomei', 'string', 10, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '10',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('schoolid', 'integer', 2, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '2',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('jufmeester', 'string', 50, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '50',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('groep', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '1',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('bijzonderheden', 'string', 500, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '500',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('zelfstandigheid', 'string', 75, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '75',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('opvang', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('dagvdweek', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('overig', 'string', 400, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '400',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('bso', 'string', 50, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '50',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('zwemdiploma', 'string', 5, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '5',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('aanmaakdatum', 'timestamp', 25, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '25',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('aanmeldwijze', 'string', 20, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '20',
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $timestampable0 = new Doctrine_Template_Timestampable(array(
             'created' => 
             array(
              'name' => 'aanmaakdatum',
             ),
             'updated' => 
             array(
              'disabled' => true,
             ),
             ));
        $this->actAs($timestampable0);
    }
}
```

**Ouders model**

```
// Connection Component Binding
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->bindComponent('Model_Ouders', 'doctrine');

/**
 * Model_Base_Ouders
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 * 
 * @property integer $ouderid
 * @property integer $userid
 * @property integer $clusterid
 * @property string $voornaam
 * @property string $tussenvoegsel
 * @property string $achternaam
 * @property string $straat
 * @property string $huisnummer
 * @property string $postcode
 * @property string $woonplaats
 * @property string $telefoonvast
 * @property string $telefoonmobiel
 * @property string $telefoonwerk
 * @property string $emailadres
 * @property string $stadspas
 * @property integer $inkomensniveau
 * @property timestamp $aanmaakdatum
 * 
 * @package    ##PACKAGE##
 * @subpackage ##SUBPACKAGE##
 * @author     ##NAME## <##EMAIL##>
 * @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 7490 2010-03-29 19:53:27Z jwage $
 */
abstract class Model_Base_Ouders extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('ouders');
        $this->hasColumn('ouderid', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('userid', 'integer', 2, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '2',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('clusterid', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('voornaam', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('tussenvoegsel', 'string', 50, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '50',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('achternaam', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('straat', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('huisnummer', 'string', 20, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '20',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('postcode', 'string', 7, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '7',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('woonplaats', 'string', 100, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '100',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('telefoonvast', 'string', 20, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '20',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('telefoonmobiel', 'string', 20, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '20',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('telefoonwerk', 'string', 20, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '20',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('stadspas', 'string', 20, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '20',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('inkomensniveau', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '1',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('aanmaakdatum', 'timestamp', 25, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '25',
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $timestampable0 = new Doctrine_Template_Timestampable(array(
             'created' => 
             array(
              'name' => 'aanmaakdatum',
             ),
             'updated' => 
             array(
              'disabled' => true,
             ),
             ));
        $this->actAs($timestampable0);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Chris

Comment: Could you paste your model definition?

Comment: I added the models, thanks for thinking along!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I noticed your model classes are named *Model_Kinderen* and *Model_Ouders* but in DQL subquery you use *Kinderen*. *Kinderen* is your database table name.

DQL is not SQL. You should work with objects and not tables.

I'm sorry if I missed something. I'm not really familiar with Zend as a framework.

Comment: Arg @ myself! You are right. I knew that already but I made the fault because I also work in Symfony and there the table classes have the same name as the tables.

Thanks a lot!